# React Native Build .ipa Files

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

How to build .ipa files in React Native for ios?
I found so many reference but not worked
I tried build from XCode but there is requires a **provosioning profile** and i don't know to make it
Btw i only need the .ipa files, i don't want to publish it in App Store
Can i build .ipa files using react native cli not using XCode? (Example like in android gradlew assembleRelease)
Can i build .ipa files without subscribe Apple Developer Account?
If i need to subscribe it, how much is it?
Nb: I'm using react-native-cli, not using Expo

Answer (score 1):

you need Apple Developer Account to be able to build .ipa

Comment: i'm just want the .ipa files, not publishing to app store, so it's still need developer account?

Comment: yes, but if you don't want to publish your app, a free account should work fine.

Comment: okayyy noted, already got a free account, btw how to generate .ipa files?, tried so much reference still fail...